# Does $\langle(4,4,4),(1,2,2)\rangle=\langle(1,2,1),(1,0,1)\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The goal is to show if $\langle(4,4,4),(1,2,2)\rangle=\langle(1,2,1),(1,0,1)\rangle$ is true or false.

My approach is based on logic.

Let $G=\langle(4,4,4),(1,2,2)\rangle$ and $F=\langle(1,2,1),(1,0,1)\rangle$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

What is said in the headline is $\forall \space u\in \mathbb{R^3}(u\in G \Leftrightarrow u \in F $).

That means $\forall \space u\in \mathbb{R^3}((u\notin G \space \vee u \in F) \wedge  (u\notin F \space \vee u \in G))$. If I negate this last expression, I get:

$\exists \space u\in \mathbb{R^3}((u\in G \space \wedge u \notin F) \vee  (u\in F \space \wedge u \notin G))$

If this last expression is true, then the headline is false. For instance $(1,2,2) \in G$ and is not a linear combination of $\{(1,2,1),(1,0,1)\}$, and so $(1,2,2) \notin F$. So the headline is false.

It's correct to prove a linear algebra issue, without linear algebra? I had tryed other ways but I couldn't do it.

Comment: `\langle` is $\langle$, and `\rangle` is $\rangle$.

Comment: Your sentence starting with **"For instance...** is sufficient to prove that the claim is false. Why bother with all the other stuff?

Comment: Every vector $(x,y,z)$ in $\langle(4,4,4),(1,2,2)\rangle$ satisfies $y=z$.  $(1,2,1)$ does not, so the two subspaces are different.

Comment: You still need some linear algebra to prove that $(1,2,2)$ is not a linear combination of $(1,2,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument **does** use linear algebra when the details are filled in: that’s how you know that $\langle 1,2,2\rangle\notin F$.

Specifically, you might argue that if $\langle x,y,z\rangle\in F$, then there are scalars $\alpha,\beta$ such that $$\langle x,y,z\rangle=\alpha\langle 1,2,1\rangle+\beta\langle 1,0,1\rangle=\langle\alpha+\beta,2\alpha,\alpha+\beta\rangle\;,$$ so $x=z$.